# vscode-jsonrpc example

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, json-rpc

I'm trying to use vscode-jsonrpc to communicate between a VSCode extension and a Json-RPC server running in a child process. The minimal code I have so far:

```ts
import * as rpc from 'vscode-jsonrpc/node';

// this is actually inside a VSCode command function 

const server = cp.spawn('servername', {
    cwd: ..., // root folder
    shell: true
}); 

const connection = rpc.createMessageConnection( 
    new rpc.StreamMessageReader(server.stdout), 
    new rpc.StreamMessageWriter(server.stdin)
); 

const request = new rpc.RequestType2("add"); 
connection.listen(); 

connection.sendRequest(request, {a: 2}, {b: 3}).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
}); 

server.on('exit', () => { console.log("server exited"); }); 
server.kill();
```

Every time I try to run the above  command the only output I get on the console is

```sh
server exited 
Error: Unexpected SIGPIPE
```

I'm a bit at a loss what's happening, also given that vscode-jsonrpc basically has no documentation. When I run the server in the shell by hand and then type in

```json
{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"add", "params":{"a":2,"b":3}, "id":1}
```

I get back

```json
{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "result":5, "id":1}
```

which is what I'm expecting.
I'm also not sure about the `shell: true` option for the spawn function, but without it I always get an ENOENT error.

Thanks for any input!